# Speeding up a Union query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query that selects teams/filters, and count how many associations match them

```
select t.name, count(c.id) from teams t
left join users u on t.id = u.team_id
left join conversation_users cu on cu.user_id = u.id
left join conversations c on cu.conversation_id = c.id
group by t.id
UNION
select 'Me', count(cu.id) from conversations c
left join conversation_users cu on cu.conversation_id = c.id
where cu.user_id = 'logged in user'
UNION
select 'All', count(c.id) from conversations c
left join apps a on c.app_id = a.id
where a.id = 'current app'
UNION
select 'Unassigned', count(c.id) from conversations c
left join apps a on c.app_id = a.id
where a.id = 'current app' and c.user_id is null
```

I'm not database genius, but this seems like a very inefficient/not scaleable approach. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

And currently it takes about 50ms to run on a small size table.

I figured I could fetch the Me, All and Unsigned filters very quickyl (around 15ms) with this approach

```
select
    count(case when c.started then 1 end) as all,
    count(case when COALESCE(c.assigned_user_id::text, c.assigned_team_id::text) is null and c.started then 1 end) as unassigned,
    count(case when c.assigned_user_id = 'clt8ojxvk0000dp2fyvwq126' and c.started then 1 end) as me
from apps a
left join conversations c on c.app_id = a.id
where a.id = 'ASnYW1-RgCl0I'
```

Could I do something similar for the teams and merge them together?

Comment: The usual suspects are missing: Postgres version, table definition. And please define "small size". What people imagine to be "small" varies by orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

Changing to UNION ALL would be an obvious step, but we have no information on how many rows are involved here so it's pretty difficult to make a performance judgement.

Comment: there can be anywhere from 100s to 10000s of conversations. Number of teams will be around 1-10

Answer (score 0):

First, you should run each query separately to determine if one of them is slowing down the query.  You should be sure that all the columns used in the `on` clauses are indexed.

Second (as suggested by David), change the `union`s to `union all`s.

You can simplify the first query:

```
select t.name, count(cu.conversation_id)
from teams t left join
     users u
     on t.id = u.team_id left join
     conversation_users cu
     on cu.user_id = u.id
group by t.name
```

Presumably, `conversation_users` is a junction table, so each row refers to one conversation.

Similarly the second query can be simplified to remove the `join`s:

```
select 'Me', count(*)
from conversation_users cu
where cu.user_id = 'logged in user'
```

And the last two might be able to be reduced to:

```
select 'All', count(*)
from conversations c
where c.app_id = 'current app'

select 'Unassigned', count(*)
from conversations c
where c.app_id = 'current app' and c.user_id is null
```

These changes make (reasonable) assumptions about the data model.

In addition, you should consider changing your data model so the ids are integers, not strings.  Using joins for keys results in lesser performance, but other factors are probably more significant in this case.

Comment: This helped a bit, I have updated the post with another approach that might be better